# Not able to populate database with contents in data.sql file Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to build a spring boot project which consists of multiple entities with relation to one another and One-to-Many mappings. I am not able to populate my database with some initial data content defined in data.sql file. I am not getting any error but the database is not getting populated.

Each entity is well defined with parameterized constructor and Getters and Setters. I am only giving the columns that should be there in the entities. These are my project entities:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details_master", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long user_id;
    
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name = "Active")
    private Boolean active;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Project> project;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private List<Task> task;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private List<Bug> bug;
```

**Project.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_master")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long project_id;
    
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name = "task_count")
    private int taskCount;
    
    @Column(name = "bug_count")
    private int bugCount;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id")
    private List<Task> task;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id")
    private List<Bug> bug;
```

**Task.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks_table")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long task_id;
    
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name = "task_status")
    private String status;
```

**Bug.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bugs_table")
public class Bug {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long bug_id;
    
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyApp?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&uselegacyDateTimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

**data.sql**

```
REPLACE INTO user_details_master (user_id, active, email, first_name, last_name, password)
VALUES (1, 1, 'admin@gmail.com', 'Admin', 'Admin', '$2a$12$k4OMYEzgvfk6bzOldQyjnesUnRxZJvsY.JyEm2VVjCW49LSgE0t4.');

REPLACE INTO roles_master (role_id, role) VALUES 
(1, 'ADMIN'),
(2, 'USER');

REPLACE INTO project_master (project_id, bug_count, description, task_count, title, fk_user_id) VALUES 
(1, 0, 'Android Application', 4, 'abcd', 1),
(2, 0, 'Android Application', 4, 'wxyz', 1);

REPLACE INTO tasks_table (task_id, description, task_status, title, fk_user_id, fk_project_id) VALUES
(1, 'faefef', 'completed', 'Book', 1, 1),
(2, 'Cffdf', 'completed', 'donate', 1, 1);

REPLACE INTO bugs_table (bug_id, description, status, title, fk_user_id, fk_project_id) VALUES
(1, 'rdgty', 'pending', 'sdfs', 1, 1);
```

I am not able to insert data in tables of MySQL Workbench. I am new to Spring Boot. Could anyone help me in solving it and explain what is wrong with my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `OnetoMany` annotation expects to find a collection so you have to substitute `Task task` with `List<Task> tasks` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have made the changes and it worked. I have modified the question, Could you please help me with this one also? Thanks in Advance

Comment: try this spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update  .Create is every time create the table .